# $\text{if} \ \ :\sin x=\sin y \Rightarrow \text{Then} \ \ x=y \ \ \text{Or} \ \ x=\pi-y$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> **Theorem1** :Prove that (without geometry):
>
> $$\text{if} \ \ :\sin x=\sin y  \Rightarrow \text{Then} \ \ x=y  \ \ \text{Or} \ \ x=\pi-y$$

---

I can prove

$$\text{if} \ \ x=y  \ \ \text{Or} \ \ x=\pi-y  \Rightarrow \text{Then} \ \ \sin x=\sin y  $$

But how prove theorem 1?

Comment: Look at a unit circle and go from there. Is that allowed, or not rigorous enough?

Comment: By the way, the claim is not true. It ought to be: "Then there is $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that either $x=y+2k\pi$ or $x=(2k+1)\pi-y$".

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin{x}-\sin{y}=2\sin\frac{x-y}{2}\cos\frac{x+y}{2},$$
which gives 
$$\sin\frac{x-y}{2}=0,$$ which is $$x-y=2\pi k,$$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$ or
$$\cos\frac{x+y}{2}=0,$$ which is
$$x+y=\pi+2\pi k$$

Comment: why ? $$x-y=2\pi k,$$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$ or
$$x+y=\pi+2\pi k$$ ?

Comment: how prove (without geometry):
$$\cos\frac{x+y}{2}=0 \to x+y=\pi+2\pi $$

Comment: @Almot1960 Note that you can always at $2\pi k$ to an angle, for $k \in \mathbb Z$. The claim that $x=y$ or $x=\pi-y$ doesn't take this into account.

Comment: @Almot1960 By the definition of $\sin$ and of $\cos$. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions